# Spark SQL query on 100 tb data

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am looking for the most optimized manner to query a static data source (hdfs) using spark SQL.

The queries are simple select with occasional filters (no joins) but I would like to show the results in mere seconds.

I have heard that bloom filter can be useful in such a scenario or structured streaming can be useful too.

Any approaches or suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider to use [PrestoDB](https://prestodb.io/) instead? From details above it sounds more suitable to setup Preso, provide access to Presto UI and run queries over your data rather than implementing arbitrary SQL processing with Spark application.

Answer (score 0):

100 tb indeed rules out in-memory solution as far as I know.
As for your question about SparkStreming; Stream processing frameworks (and spark streaming is not a classic one in this sense, since it does micro-batching) does not fit the use case you describe.

I streaming you have your queries (or filters in your case) standing, compiled and ready to go, whereas the data stream is continuously pumped through them, manipulating the data.

As far as your queries; can the `select` query be ran on any arbitrary column, or is it predefined?